# Describe the region (point, line, or plane), if any, that is the intersection of these planes?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

The following equations represent planes in $R^3$:

$y-x-3z = 1$
$z+2y-3x=-4$
$3y-4x-2z=-3$

If put into augmented form, you get
-1   1   -3   |   1
-3   2   1    |   -4
-4   3   -2   |   -3

And the RREF of the system is
1   0   -7   |   6
0   1   -10   |   7
0   0   0   |   0

And finally, the result is $(6+7t, 7+10t, t)$
Now, my question is simple. How exactly would I know if the intersection is either a point, line, or plane?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution space to the system of equations has as many dimensions as the number of free variables. Lines are one-dimensional and planes are two-dimensional, so...

Comment: So in this case, $t$ is the only free variable. Does that mean the intersection is a Point?

Comment: No. Clearly, there’s clearly more than one point in this set.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

your solution is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
6\\7\\0
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
7\\10\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and this the equation of a line.

Comment: I'm working on another set of equations, and the solution for it is $(-1+2t-f, t, f)$. This doesn't follow the form of a line, would this be a plane?

Comment: Yes, if $t$ and $f$ are independent parameters ( see the answer of @amd).